# Communication between Qt programs for managing access to device

Tags: c++, qt

I plan on having several programs, developed on Qt, access the same device, which is an acquisition board. But they can't both access it at the same time (guess what happens). **I'd like to know what is the best way for two or more programs to communicate to negotiate access.**

What I envision is some bool variable on a shared space being set to true every time one program accesses the device. Then, when another program checks that bool to see if it can communicate or not, it decides on what to do.

Also, notice the number of programs running that could potentially access the device is undefined. One of them may be closed, or another opened. I think you get the deal.

I'm checking `QSharedMemory` class for this. Is this the best way?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for all platforms Qt is supported on, or just one in particular?

Comment: For Linux and Windows for sure. Maybe mac in the future.